# Unbound value in recursive function (Beginner OCaml)

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Code:

```
let isPrime x =
    let checkZero d = match (x mod d, x mod d + 2, intRoot x < d) with
        | (0,_,_)    -> false
        | (_,0,_)    -> false
        | (_,_,true) -> true
        | _          -> checkZero (d + 6) in
    match x with
        | 0 -> false
        | 1 -> true
        | 2 -> true
        | 3 -> true
        | _ -> match (x mod 2, x mod 3) with
            | (0,_) -> false
            | (_,0) -> false
            | _     -> checkZero 5
```

Error:

```
line 9, characters 24-33:
Error: Unbound value checkZero
```

Which refers to the recursive call `checkZero (d+6)`

I've tried placing the checkZero function as a `let ... in` in the final `checkZero 5` call and added/removed the `x` parameter in the `checkZero` function in case there was an error with the definition.

(Running OCaml downloaded in the past week on OSX through homebrew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function to be able to call itself you need to declare it as recursive:

```
let rec checkZero d ...
```